# Bot framework get the ServiceUrl of embedded chat control page

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I want to embed the chat control to many websites and I want to get the Url of the website that I've embedded in order to my bot can get the Data matching with the Website URL. However, when I embed the iframe generated from WebChat, I always get the same ServiceUrl and that's **https://webchat.botframework.com/**, it isn't the Url of the website, so how can I embed the chat control to any website and my bot can get the website Url not the Url of the WebChat or DirectLine.

Here's what I've tried:[Direct-Line chat control](https://codepaste.net/umd5gv)

Here's the result I've tested with my published bot: [image: Result]

I've noticed that, when I've tested my bot with the Bot Framework Emulator, it always return the exact Url of the sender (in case of local testingm, it will return http://localhost:XXXX/). So how can we do like this?

Comment: This does not seem to be Robot Framework related, the test automation tool by the same name.

Comment: i know it just an emulator for testing, but what I want to know here is there anyway we can get it when we publish the bot

Comment: You can host your own webchat control. refer this link https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: I don't tend to host my own web-Chat control, what I want is embed it to my customer website and I want to get their website domain

Comment: You can't; however you can consider using backChannel to send something from the webpage to the bot via events

Comment: @EzequielJadib okay, can you show me how to make a backChannel?

Comment: @EzequielJadib Have you discovered other ways to do this? Is it possible to embed the URL in TurnContext?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a way to achieve this would be by using BackChannel, which adds the ability for a bot to communicate with a page that embeds the bot through WebChat. It will a allow you to:

- Send events to a page that hosts an instance of a WebChat
- Listen for events from the page that hosts an instance of a WebChat

The first piece is, of course, the HTML page, which will contain what you put together, plus the logic to send/listen to events. The sample page with the basic logic can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html) and below is the image with the events related code.

[image: BackChannel events]

Now, you need to prepare your bot to listen and send events. There is a [sample](https://github.com/ryanvolum/backChannelBot/blob/master/app.js) in `Node.js`, that shows how to do that.

Porting that in `C#`, is as easy as listen and sending to activities of type Event. A sample code for that (using the events of the HTML page mentioned before):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event &&
        string.Equals(activity.Name, "buttonClicked", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        // return our reply to the user
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("I see that you just pushed that button");
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }

    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        // return our reply to the user
        var reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Event;
        reply.Name = "changeBackground";
        reply.Value = activity.Text;
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Bottom line, in your HTML page you will have to send an event to the bot, with the page URL and the bot will have to listen to that event to get the value

Comment: Sample links are broken, please update if possible.