# Microsoft Bot framework: Sending Message on connect

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm new with Microsoft Bot framework. Right now I'm testing my code on Emulator. I want to send Hello message as soon as your connect. Following is my code.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
   appId: "-- APP ID --",
   appPassword: "-- APP PASS --"
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/message/',connector.listen());

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    session.send("Hello");
    session.beginDialog('/createSubscription');
});
```

Above code sends Hello message when user initiate a conversation. I want to send this message as soon as user connects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hook into the `conversationUpdate` event and check when the bot is added. After that, you can just post a message or begin a new dialog (as in the code below I extracted from the [ContosoFlowers Node.js sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers), though there are many [others](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/search?l=JavaScript&q=conversationUpdate&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) doing the same).

```
// Send welcome when conversation with bot is started, by initiating the root dialog
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                bot.beginDialog(message.address, '/');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks... Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Just one more thing can i also get list of all users connected to bot ?

Comment: Mmmm I'm not aware of something to do that. You should do that manually, storing the users that started a conversation with the bot.

Comment: Then there would be some way of checking if user is currently connected or not ?

Comment: no...if by connected you mean "actively talking with the bot" then... again, just use the incoming messages and add some logic there.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send a token along from webchat and use it within the dialog?

Comment: You could explore BackChannel and see if that suits your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825048/bot-framework-get-the-serviceurl-of-embedded-chat-control-page/42858407#42858407

Comment: Can we not send any rich cards from here? is there any way to get session here?