# MS BotBuilder : How can the bot receive parameters and initiate conversation at webchat start

Tags: botframework

I'm using the direct-line method to communicate with this bot :

```
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID || config.appId,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD || config.appPassword
});


// Initialize bot
var bot = universalBot(connector);

var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || port, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});



var botListener = connector.listen();
server.post('/api/messages', (req, resp) => {
    token = req.query.token;
    console.log(token); //prints the token to the terminal
    botListener(req, resp);
});

var msg = new builder.Message()
        .text(notification);
        //.address(address)

    bot.send(msg, function (err) {
        // Return success/failure
        res.status(err ? 500 : 200);
        res.end();
    });
```

In order to pro-actively send the message i still need the address of the user and conversation id.

Is there a way to obtain these information at the time this initialisation on the browser ;

```
var bot = {
                id: params['botid'] || 'botid',
                name: params['botname'] || 'botname',
                screen: params['screen'] || null
            };

 BotChat.App({
                directLine: {
                    //secret: params['s'],
                    token: params['t'],
                    //domain: params['domain'],
                    //webSocket: params['webSocket']
                },
                user: user, //Need to access this user object at server on the webchat start
                bot: bot
            }, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"));
```

Or any other way where the bot can start the conversation when the user loads the html in the browser.

UPDATE : The conversationUpdate dialog serves for triggering and initiating a dialog, but how can I access the parameter (token) and user object sent along, inside conversationUpdate dialog?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to send a welcome message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Bot framework: Sending Message on connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048088/microsoft-bot-framework-sending-message-on-connect)

Comment: @EzequielJadib Partially, here I need to send a token parameter as well, please see the update. thx

Comment: Why you need the token in the first place? It sounds something is wrong is you need to send the token to the bot.

Comment: I need the token to authenticate with a webservice. If not the token, anyway I can get the user object there?

Comment: The user is accessible from the Bot.. the From value

Comment: I believe you are looking for `message.address.user`

Comment: @PavelVeller : `message.address.user` has only 1 attribute `id`. I am sending 3 - id, name, token. So this is not the one i am sending from client.

Comment: I am afraid you can't get what you want but to tell you with confidence I need to see how you are sending this to the bot.

Comment: @PavelVeller : Please check the updated code defining the user object. It is being sent as an attribute of the object passed to BotChat.App()

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want your bot to prompt the user with something like `Hi, what can I help you with today?` the minute the webchat loads, right? I haven't tried the direct line, always used the provided `iframe`, and here's what I do in my bot to send the welcome message:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', (message) => {
    (message.membersAdded || [])
        .filter((identity) => identity.id == message.address.bot.id)
        .forEach((identity) => {
            const reply = new builder.Message()
                .address(message.address)
                .text("Hi, How can I help you today?");

            bot.send(reply);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the [backchannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). With this, you can send values to your bot.  the backchannel documentation is at the bottom of the readme on that repo.