# Sign in Card with username/password fields

Tags: c#, botframework

I'd like to create a sign-in card that is not a link to a webpage to sign in to. Something that behaves something like this

[image]

All of the resources I've found online only show the button link like [image]

Whose code looks something like this

```
var replytoconversation = context.MakeMessage();
replytoconversation.Text = "Authorize your Account";
replytoconversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

var cardbuttons = new List<CardAction>();

cardbuttons.Add(new CardAction
{
     Title = "connect",
     Value = "http://mail.google.com",
     Type = ActionTypes.Signin

 });


 SigninCard plcard = new SigninCard("Log in to your account", cardbuttons);

 Attachment plattachment = plcard.ToAttachment();
 replytoconversation.Attachments.Add(new SigninCard("Log in to your account", cardbuttons).ToAttachment());
 await context.PostAsync(replytoconversation);
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible, first of all because most of the channels doesn't support a textbox control. Possible in the WebChat you can do something custom.. I don't think it makes a lot of sense to do it in that way; plus no one would like the idea of writing their password in the chat (where it will be logged)... Explain a bit better your scenario and we might have some ideas.

Comment: The application would be behind a secure server the users have to log in to with a custom webchat channel so there is a bit more security than just entering info. Do you know of any resources creating a webchat with a textbox control I could look to?

Comment: Not really. I mentioned the webchat because I know it's the only channel that could support a textbox control. Still, I don't think it's a good idea to have that within the chat control. One alternative you could explore, is handling the auth in the webpage but outside the bot/chat and communicate to the bot from the same webpage using the BackChannel capabilities. See [Bot framework get the ServiceUrl of embedded chat control page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825048/bot-framework-get-the-serviceurl-of-embedded-chat-control-page/42858407#42858407)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible using the card system in the way you are asking. The only way I can think of at the moment would be to create a login web page alongside your web interface chat (if that's what you are using) and embed the web page in the chat bot (I've done something like this for a similar reason). This is a useful way of dealing with a number of things, such as connecting to a system that does not have an api. I know it's not the exact answer you want, but it's really the only way to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating this as ive been working on it lately. If you use Adaptive-Cards, you can add in Input boxes using AdaptiveTextInput. Link these to a submit function and you can have the user input their details in,then pass them to another function. Here, you can either cast out of the bot to an auth protocol (not sure about how, havent tried yet), or you can do what I'm doing, and use a http/ftp database to authenticate data. Not that secure, but depends on what you are using it for.